# Alternatively assign values to two column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks as follows

```
    Datetime                Message

0   2021-12-20 09:50:08.819 Current sidewing pressure: 3362 
1   2021-12-20 09:50:08.820 Current sidewing pressure: 3303 
2   2021-12-20 09:50:08.839 Current sidewing pressure: 3398 
3   2021-12-20 09:50:08.839 Current sidewing pressure: 3279 
4   2021-12-20 09:50:08.860 Current sidewing pressure: 3398 
5   2021-12-20 09:50:08.860 Current sidewing pressure: 3303 
6   2021-12-20 09:50:08.879 Current sidewing pressure: 3303
```

And I am trying to alternatively assign those values to two new columns called Left and Right.

Something as follows

```
    Datetime                Message                          Left   Right

0   2021-12-20 09:50:08.819 Current sidewing pressure: 3362  3362
1   2021-12-20 09:50:08.820 Current sidewing pressure: 3303         3303
2   2021-12-20 09:50:08.839 Current sidewing pressure: 3398  3398
3   2021-12-20 09:50:08.839 Current sidewing pressure: 3279         3279
4   2021-12-20 09:50:08.860 Current sidewing pressure: 3398  3398
5   2021-12-20 09:50:08.860 Current sidewing pressure: 3303         3303
6   2021-12-20 09:50:08.879 Current sidewing pressure: 3303  3303
```

Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: a single column that alternates as `Left` `Right` would probably be more useful

Comment: @anon01 True, but I need these two columns for my special case

Comment: What is the special case

Comment: @anon01 I have data from a robot that alternatively returns pressure from two sensors alongside its position, it would make it easier for me to have average pressure from each sensors and position in one row to feed it to a ML algo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iloc[::2]` to extract every other value (`::2` for even indices values, and `1::2` for odd indices values) and assign to a column:

```
vals = df.Message.str.extract('(\d+)$')
df['Right'] = vals.iloc[::2]
df['Left'] = vals.iloc[1::2]

df
                  Datetime                          Message Right  Left
0  2021-12-20 09:50:08.819  Current sidewing pressure: 3362  3362   NaN
1  2021-12-20 09:50:08.820  Current sidewing pressure: 3303   NaN  3303
2  2021-12-20 09:50:08.839  Current sidewing pressure: 3398  3398   NaN
3  2021-12-20 09:50:08.839  Current sidewing pressure: 3279   NaN  3279
4  2021-12-20 09:50:08.860  Current sidewing pressure: 3398  3398   NaN
5  2021-12-20 09:50:08.860  Current sidewing pressure: 3303   NaN  3303
6  2021-12-20 09:50:08.879  Current sidewing pressure: 3303  3303   NaN
```